# Avoid a variable optimized out with multithread C++

Tags: c++, winapi, optimization

I'm making a program in C++ and I've a Thread working with `.detach();` and when I try to access another thread from it, the debugger say that the response has been optimized out and I can't access it.
Is there any way to "fix" that?

Here you have the code:

```
int foos;
unsigned int ReadProcess(HANDLE phandle, unsigned int address) {
    unsigned int Pointer;
    ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (void*)(address), &Pointer, sizeof(address), 0);
    return Pointer;
}

void foo()
{
    while (1) {
        if (foos == 1) { break; }
        volatile unsigned int xPointer, xBaseaddress = 0x002CF7DC, xoffset = 0x448, xoffset1 = 0x198, xoffset2 = 0x498, xoffset3 = 0x268, xoffset4 = 0x24;
        HANDLE phandle = GetProcessHandle("Speed Calculator");
        DWORD Base = (DWORD)GetBaseAddress(phandle);
        xPointer = Base + xBaseaddress; //xPointer optimized out here
        xPointer = ReadProcess(phandle, xPointer) + xoffset; //and here
        xPointer = ReadProcess(phandle, xPointer) + xoffset1; //and here
        xPointer = ReadProcess(phandle, xPointer) + xoffset2; //and here
        xPointer = ReadProcess(phandle, xPointer) + xoffset3; //and here
        xPointer = ReadProcess(phandle, xPointer) + xoffset4; //and here
        if (!SendMessage(textBox1, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)("IS: ") + xPointer))//and because of that, here
            MessageBox(0, "Error: " + GetLastError(), "Error", MB_OK);
        Sleep(299);
    }
}

void main() {

                foos = 0;
                std::thread first(foo);
                first.detach();

}
```

I've ignored part of my code because it's mostly a win32 API interaction.

Comment: Turn off optimizations?

Comment: How can I turn it off in this part?

Comment: `foos` has not been declared.

Comment: can you post the assembler produced by foo?

Comment: Your code has a race condition, and thus undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio Update 3 (or later) you could try to use the [/Zo (Enhance Optimized Debugging)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn785163.aspx) compiler option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler has been called with parameters requesting that the code be optimized.

### Visual Studio Example

Have a look at your solution configuration in Visual Studio (the drop down where you have either `Release` or `Debug` to select).

If you change to `Debug` then the variables should not be optimized out and you can see what is happening.

What happens when you change the solution configuration is that Visual Studio sets the parameters for that configuration when it call the compiler. In this case we would prefer the `/Od (Disabled)` flag for `Configuration properties→C/C++→Optimization→Optimization` as opposed to `/O2 (Maximize Speed)`.

During debug you can also open a "Threads" window to see the threads that are created.

Comment: Optimizations have little to do with build configurations, except that optimizations are usually turned off in debug builds, but that is coincidental. See [Compiler Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx) that do control optimizations.

Comment: @IInspectable It's not coincidental, it is the [documented default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aafb762y.aspx) for `Debug`.

Comment: No, it isn't. It is the default used by the compiler, unless another optimization option is used. The connection to the debug configuration is purely coincidental. A debug configuration could choose any optimization, or have a different name altogether. It's not the configuration that changes code generation. It's the compiler options (collectively controlled through configurations for convenience only).

Comment: You make a good point about compiler options being the direct points of control for these options. But if something behaves according to the documented default, then it is no coincidence. Maybe coincidental doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: The compiler knows nothing about IDE's or build systems. It may be that Visual Studio's default Win32 app wizard's default is to not emit any optimization compiler options for a configuration it happens to call *"Debug"*. But that is neither documented, nor contractual. It is purely coincidental. Your answer would be more precise, as well as less susceptible to future change, if you mentioned the compiler options. You **can** add, that an easy way to change that option with Visual Studio (up to VS 2015) is to select the Debug configuration. But that should not be the gist of your answer.

Comment: It's right [at the top of the page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aafb762y.aspx) I linked to. `/Od (Disable (Debug))`. And it states: `This option is the default`. No wizards.

Comment: You are missing the point entirely. The *"Debug"* in *"/Od (Disable (Debug))"* is not the same as the *"Debug"* in the configuration drop-down list of Visual Studio. The latter is the **name** of the configuration, as specified in the respective *.sln file. It could be called *"Fred"* just as well, or there may not even be a configuration named *"Debug"*. If you want to disable optimizations you have to remove all optimization compiler options. This may or may not be possible by switching configurations.

Comment: *"This option is the default"* simply means: If no other optimization compiler options are specified, the code is compiled without any optimizations (vs. a fixed set of common optimizations, for example). It does not mean, that it is the default for a configuration that happens to have the name *"Debug"*. The compiler does not know or care about configurations or configuration names.